# Point `apk` to install packages to correct `site-packages`

Tags: python, dockerfile, alpine-linux, python-3.12

Certain (`py3-pandas`, `py3-scipy`) packages installed through `apk` on `python:3.12-alpine` are not accessible since they are installed in `/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages` inspite of specifying `$PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages`

For reference, here's the relevant portion of the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.12-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages

RUN apk add --no-cache \
                gcc g++ libffi-dev musl-dev \
                py3-pandas py3-scipy \
 && pip3 install pip-tools

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.in  .
RUN pip-compile requirements.in > requirements.txt \
 && pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["sh"]
```

Comment: Why are you overriding the default `PYTHONPATH` anyway?

Comment: Because although the container has `python3.12` installed, for some reason everything else, (in this case, `pip`) still points to the `3.11` install/dep location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apk` hard-codes the binaries it creates; there is no sane way to install these packages from `apk` and expect them to continue to work on a completely different Python version. If you examine the `.apk` file itself, you will notice that it contains these paths inside the package; there is nothing you can do anymore at that point to change what's inside the APK file.

As a crude workaround, you can put multiple directories in `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH`; these variables are additive. Demo:

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages \
python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
```

Output:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python312.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.12', '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages']
```

So, you can speculatively set `PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages` and it will use the 3.11 packages *in addition to* the default locations which are in `sys.path` by default.

That still doesn't remove the problem that packages compiled for 3.11 might simply not work on 3.12. In fact, if you try, it fails:

```
/ # PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload python -c 'import pandas'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.12 from "/usr/local/bin/python"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.25.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

(The above also coincidentally demonstrates how to put multiple directories in `PYTHONPATH`; separate them with a colon.)

So, in summary, you need to compile these packages yourself. If you wanted to, you could do it once and put the results in an APK repository of your own, and download from there instead if you have multiple images or nodes which need to have these packages installed.

Comment: `_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-musl.so` is in `/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/`; if the file name didn't hard-code the Python version, you could probably add it to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and cross your fingers - but alas, it does.